# Understanding the pickled object size

Tags: python, numpy, serialization, pickle

I execute the following line in Python interpreter:

```
len(pickle.dumps([numpy.random.random(384).tolist()]*55))
```

It gives 3584.

Given that `numpy.random.random` produces 8-byte floats, the data being pickled is 384 * 8 * 55 = 168,960 bytes. How come `len` gives such a small number?

Comment: @Timus Sure, so what? Why is it so small?

Comment: what is  `(384 + 55)*8`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you multiply a list of a list, a shallow copy of the inner list is added.

For example:

```py
a = [[7, 8, 9]] * 5
id(a[0]) == id(a[1])  # True
```

In other words, a is equivalent to:

```py
reference_to_inner_list = [7, 8, 9]
a = [
    reference_to_inner_list,
    reference_to_inner_list,
    reference_to_inner_list,
    reference_to_inner_list,
    reference_to_inner_list,
]
```

pickle serializes this object as it is, so the serialized object is also a list of references.

Luckily we have a human-readable protocol available that actually visualize this.

```py
pickle.dumps([[7,8,9]], protocol=0)
pickle.dumps([[7,8,9]]*5, protocol=0)
```

Outputs:

```
b'(lp0\n(lp1\nI7\naI8\naI9\naa.'
b'(lp0\n(lp1\nI7\naI8\naI9\naag1\nag1\nag1\nag1\na.'
               ^    ^    ^     ^    ^    ^    ^
               7    8    9    r-2  r-3  r-4  r-5
```

Where `r-2`, ... , `r-5` are the 2nd through 5th references, respectively.
As you can see, the references are very small compared to the actual list.

This is exactly the reason why your object is so small as well.
Your object consists of a list of 384 floats and 54 references to that list.

If the object were a flat list, the size would explode because it would no longer be a reference.

```py
len(pickle.dumps(numpy.random.random(384).tolist()*55))
# 190156
```

This behavior is essential for pickle when dealing with, for example, tree structure data.
If pickle cannot deserialize a reference as a reference, the tree structure will be corrupted.

### Edit:

As for the object in question, no compression is performed because they are floats.
For example, as shown below, the size of a float array is approximately the number of elements x 9 bytes (8 bytes for the data, 1 byte for the append operation, I guess).

```py
len(pickle.dumps(numpy.zeros(384*55).tolist()))
# 190156
384*55*9
# 190080
```

This shows that no compression is performed for this one, but it does not mean that pickle does no compression at all.
For example, if values were integer, as shown below, it would be smaller.

```py
len(pickle.dumps(numpy.zeros(384*55, dtype=numpy.int64).tolist()))
# 42298
384*55*2
# 42240
```

So, pickle does some sort of compression (or encoding), just not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your creating a nested list whereas there are 55 copies of a list of 384 random floats between 0 and 1. This is likely not what you expected but you can the output here

```
import numpy as np
res = [np.random.random(384).tolist()]*55
print(res)
```

If your looking to make integer lists you would want to go with np.random.randint(0,9) instead.

As to why the specific size of the pickle object, that is a little more complex and not a direct calculation based on byte sizes. This is a result of the pickle data format, which does not store the data directly as a string but rather uses a python specific set of opcodes to break down python objects and store them as a series of bytes in a compressed manner. The unpickling process reads these opcodes to reconstruct the objects back into their original states.

If you view the pickle object in its bytes format you will not see anything that resembles the values from your list because everything has been encoded using it's own internal language.

You will not get a bytes count because it's a compressed format, is one answer. If you want to make sense of the exact size of the object you will have to dig into the storage size of each opcode used in your file and build up the storage consumption from there, then account for it being stores as bytes.

References:

[Pickle Opcodes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f45ef5edabb1cc0748f3326e7114b8aaa0424392/Lib/pickle.py#L107)

[Source - Where encoding happens](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f45ef5edabb1cc0748f3326e7114b8aaa0424392/Lib/pickle.py#L789)

[Pickler class object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f45ef5edabb1cc0748f3326e7114b8aaa0424392/Lib/pickle.py#L407)

Comment: That is correct and that is what I expected. How does this explain the size of the pickled object?

Comment: If you do want to build something out that breaks down a pickle file into its opcodes, something like an object viewer, that would be awesome. I've never seen anything like that before.

Comment: Could you link to the documentation that says that pickle compresses?

Comment: there aren't 55 `copies`.  It's a list with 55 references to the same list.